# Stopping event bubbling in Javascript Classes

Tags: javascript, class, oop, dom, javascript-objects

I am trying to make a Class in Javascript for creating Tab Objects to insert in the DOM.

The tabs have a title div and a close button inside them. They also have event listeners.

For the tab itself: A **select()** onclick method that adds a **.tab--selected** CSS class to the tab the user has clicked on, then it removes that same CSS class from the current "selected" tab.

As for the close button: It has a **delete()** onclick method that just removes the tab that is linked to it's Tab Class instance from the DOM.

My problem is that due to Event Bubbling when I click on that close button it also triggers the **select()** method of the tab im trying to delete.

So my question is: Is it possible to use **event.stopPropagation()** in Javascript classes? Or any other way to stop event bubbling inside a class method?

Here is my code,

In Typescript:

```
interface forTab {
    tab: Element;
    title: Element;
    closeButton: Element;
    
    select(): void;
    delete(): void;
}

let counter: number = 0;
let tabs: Tab[] = [];

class Tab implements forTab {
    tab: Element = document.createElement("div");
    title: Element = document.createElement("div");
    closeButton: HTMLButtonElement = document.createElement("button");

    constructor() {
        counter++;
        this.tab.classList.add("tab", "tab--selected");
        this.title.innerHTML = `New tab ${counter}`;
        this.closeButton.innerHTML = 'X';

        this.tab.onclick = this.select.bind(this);
        this.closeButton.onclick = this.delete.bind(this);

        this.tab.append(this.title, this.closeButton);
    }

    select(): void {
        const selectedTab: Element = document.querySelector(".tab--selected")!;
        if (selectedTab === this.tab) return;

        if (selectedTab !== null) {
            selectedTab.classList.remove("tab--selected");
        }

        this.tab.classList.add("tab--selected");

        console.log("select() just ran");
    }

    delete(): void {
        // run the select() method of the class instance that was
        // created after this one.
        tabs[tabs.indexOf(this) + 1].select();
        this.tab.remove();

        // It would be great if select() did'nt run after running this.
        console.log("delete() just ran");
    }
}

const tabContainer: Element = document.getElementById("tab-container")!;
const addTabBtn: Element = document.getElementById("add-tab")!;


function AddNewTab(): void {
    const newTab: Tab = new Tab();
    tabs.push(newTab);
    newTab.select();

    tabContainer.append(newTab.tab);
}

addTabBtn.addEventListener("click", AddNewTab);
```

And Javascript:

```
let counter = 0;
let tabs = [];

class Tab {
    constructor() {
        counter++;

        this.tab = document.createElement("div");
        this.title = document.createElement("div");
        this.closeButton = document.createElement("button");

        this.tab.classList.add("tab", "tab--selected");
        this.title.innerHTML = `New tab ${counter}`;
        this.closeButton.innerHTML = 'X';

        this.tab.onclick = this.select.bind(this);
        this.closeButton.onclick = this.delete.bind(this);
        this.tab.append(this.title, this.closeButton);
    }

    select() {
        const selectedTab = document.querySelector(".tab--selected");
        if (selectedTab === this.tab) return;

        if (selectedTab !== null) {
            selectedTab.classList.remove("tab--selected");
        }

        this.tab.classList.add("tab--selected");
        console.log("select() just ran");
    }

    delete() {
        // run the select() method of the class instance that was
        // created after this one.
        tabs[tabs.indexOf(this) + 1].select();
        this.tab.remove();

        // It would be great if select() did'nt run after running this.
        console.log("delete() just ran");
    }
}

const tabContainer = document.getElementById("tab-container");
const addTabBtn = document.getElementById("add-tab");

function AddNewTab() {
    const newTab = new Tab();
    tabs.push(newTab);
    newTab.select();
    tabContainer.append(newTab.tab);
}

addTabBtn.addEventListener("click", AddNewTab);
```

HTML and CSS I'm using:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        #tab-container {
            display: flex;
            background-color: black;
        }

        .tab {
            display: flex;
            background-color: gray;
            border: 4px solid lime;
        }

        .tab--selected {
            background-color: orange;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="tab-container"></div>
    <button id="add-tab" type="button">Add new tab</button>
    <script src="Tab.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I'd prefer doing this without Jquery or any Javascript framework.

Comment: Event bubbling has nothing to do with classes. Yes, it's possible to call `event.stopPropagation()` just like you can call it anywhere else.

Comment: Problem is: I am adding both select() and delete() methods to both this.tab and this.closeButton and then binding them to their class instance. If I do that, I cant do stopPropagation() since the value of this is just the tab object itself, not the event.

Comment: You can use arrow functions

Comment: The value of `this` is never the event, it's usually the element to which the listener was bound. The event is passed as an argument to the listener! `delete(event) { event.stopPropagation(); … }`

Comment: Hey Bergi, could you post your comment as an answer? Just wanted to say thank you so much.